# Cancel Alarm and notification set in a Fragment from another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-notifications, android-alarms

I am trying to cancel an alarm set in a Fragment , from another Fragment, how I can do this?

**InserisciOra.java**  (the Fragment in which I set the alarm)

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyReceiver.class);
if(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, 
    myIntent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null){

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent,0);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: both fragment are of same activity?

Comment: @Fahim  yes  both fragment are of same activity

Comment: do you  have multiple Alarm/notifications?

Comment: Actually not, but I will add other Alarms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MyReceiver.class);
      pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, myIntent,0);
      alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
      // cancel the alarm
      alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
      // delete the PendingIntent
      pendingIntent.cancel()
```

Comment: Thank's David , i tried your code but when i cancel my alarm and then I set it ,the alarm don't work :(

Comment: Please explain what you mean. Maybe you also didn't delete the `PendingIntent` so that the code you use to determine whether or not the alarm is still set probably doesn't work. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes the problem was that I didn't delete the PendingIntent , thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

use [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)) method to cancel your alarm

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity().,
     MyReceiver.class);

   PendingIntent pendingIntent
    = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(),
      0, myIntent, 0);

   AlarmManager alarmManager
     = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: where I have to put this code? In the Fragment without anything else?

Comment: the problem is that i just want to reset the alarm, in this way the alarm is deleted and I can't set a new alarm in the future

Comment: ofcourse you can set it again. the same way how you are doing it right now